# How to generate Helm charts config file with JSON data

Tags: json, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I want to generate complex JSON with HELM template

I have a template:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data:
  config.json: |
  {
    "test": "{{ $Value }}",
    "services": {
      {{- range $k, $v := $.Values.services }}
      "{{ $k | upper }}_PATH": "{{ $k }}",
      {{- end }}
     }
  }
```

Helm chars generates json:

```
{
  "test": "test",
  "services": {
     "S1_PATH": "/t1",
     "S2_PATH": "/t2",
     "S2_PATH": "/t3",
   }
}
```

Problem is that JSON is not valid as it has a **trailing comma**. How to update the template to resolve this?

Comment: You could find a answer for your question on this other StackOverflow thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42662525/go-template-remove-the-last-comma-in-range-loop

Answer (score 2):

If you update the template like this, it should work.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data:
  config.json: |
  {
    "test": "{{ $Value }}",
    "services": {
      {{- range $k, $v := $.Values.services }}
      {{ if ne $k 0 }},{{ end }}
      "{{ $k | upper }}_PATH": "{{ $k }}"
      {{- end }}
     }
  }
```

For the first service (index is 0) it does not place a comma and for all others it places one in front.

Answer (score 0):

How about straightforward:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data:
  config.json: {{ .Values.servicePathes | toJson }}
```

```yaml
# values.yaml
servicePathes:
 services:
  S1_PATH: "s1"
  S2_PATH: "s2"
  S3_PATH: "s3"
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I dont undersood your question correctly, but to avoid trailing comma, you should remove it from your template.
Plus I see you should use `.Values.services` instead of `$.Values.services`

template:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data:
  config.json: |
  {
    "services": {
      {{- range $k, $v := .Values.services }}
      "{{ $k | upper }}_PATH": "{{ $k }}"
      {{- end }}
     }
  }
```

result:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data:
  config.json: |
  {
    "services": {
      "S1_PATH": "s1"
      "S2_PATH": "s2"
      "S3_PATH": "s3"
     }
  }
```

If this i snot you expected - please add more info in your question.

Comment: It is wrong as you have to have commas after s1 and s2. If you try to parse it you will get an exception.