# Remove character after a range function - Helm

Tags: azure, kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm, configmap

I am slightly new to Helm, but i am trying to remove a character if its the last run of the iteration with range. This deployment is for a config map for logstash pulling from an azure storage blob that has logs from Azure Event Hubs in.

Values file:

```yaml
user: user
azureStorageConnection: "https://azure-storage-url"
azureStorageContainer: user
endpoints:
  - endpointName: "TEST-1"
    endpointURL: "https://fake-url.com"
  - endpointName: "TEST-2"
    endpointURL: "https://fake-url.com"
Release:
  Name: production

logstashVersion: 7.10.0
```

Config map I'm trying to deploy:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-config
data:
  conf.conf: |
    input {
      azure_event_hubs {
        config_mode => "advanced"
        {{- if .Values.azureStorageConnection }}
        storage_connection => "{{ .Values.azureStorageConnection }}"
        storage_container => "{{ .Values.azureStorageContainer }}"
        {{- end }}
        decorate_events => true
        add_field => {
          "type" => "azure"
          "user" => "{{ .Values.user }}"
        }
        event_hubs => [
        {{- range $endpoints := .Values.endpoints }}
            { {{- $endpoints.endpointName | quote }} => {
            event_hub_connection => {{ $endpoints.endpointURL | quote }}
            consumer_group => {{- $endpoints.endpointName | quote }}
          }},
        {{- end }}
          ]
        }
      }
```

What is currently outputting as:

```yaml
data:
  conf.conf: |
    input {
      azure_event_hubs {
        config_mode => "advanced"
        storage_connection => "https://azure-storage-url.com"
        storage_container => "user"
        decorate_events => true
        add_field => {
          "type" => "azure"
          "user" => "user"
        }
        event_hubs => [
            {"TEST-1" => {
            event_hub_connection => "https://fake-url.com"
            consumer_group =>"TEST-1"
          }},
            {"TEST-2" => {
            event_hub_connection => "https://fake-url.com"
            consumer_group =>"TEST-2"
          }},
          ]
        }
      }
```

This is how i am trying to get it:

```yaml
data:
  conf.conf: |
    input {
      azure_event_hubs {
        config_mode => "advanced"
        storage_connection => "https://azure-storage-url.com"
        storage_container => "user"
        decorate_events => true
        add_field => {
          "type" => "azure"
          "user" => "user"
        }
        event_hubs => [
            {"TEST-1" => {
            event_hub_connection => "https://fake-url.com"
            consumer_group =>"TEST-1"
          }},
            {"TEST-2" => {
            event_hub_connection => "https://fake-url.com"
            consumer_group =>"TEST-2"
          }}
          ]
        }
      }
```

As you can see i want to be able to tell helm that after the last iteration, to not add the "," at the end of the last event_hub block closer.

Would anyone know what i can add to my configmap to be able to remove characters if its the last iteration?

Many thanks in advance :)

**Solution:**

In the end i amended my values to:

```yaml
variables:
  user: user
  AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION: "event_hub_storage_url"
  EVENT_HUBS:
    - ENDPOINTNAME: "event_hub_1"
      ENDPOINTURL: "Endpoint=fake-url-1"
      EVENT_HUB_CONTAINER: "event_hub_1"
    - ENDPOINTNAME: "event_hub_2"
      ENDPOINTURL: "Endpoint=fake-url-2"
      EVENT_HUB_CONTAINER: "event_hub_2"
```

and the charts configmap to the following:

```yaml
     input {
      azure_event_hubs {
        config_mode => "advanced"
        {{- if .Values.azureStorageConnection }}
        storage_connection => "{{ .Values.azureStorageConnection }}"
        {{- end }}
        decorate_events => true
        add_field => {
          "type" => "azure"
          "user" => "{{ .Values.user }}"
        }
        event_hubs => [
        {{- $length := len .Values.event_hubs }}
        {{- range $index, $event_hubs := .Values.event_hubs }}
            { {{- $event_hubs.endpointName | quote }} => {
            event_hub_connection => {{ $event_hubs.endpointURL | quote }}
            storage_container => "{{ $event_hubs.event_hub_container }}"
          }}{{ $position := add $index 1}}{{ if lt $position $length }},{{ end }}
        {{- end }}
          ]
        }
      }
```

This way i can tell it the length equals the amount of (event_hubs in my case], and to find out what position its in, and once the position is no longer less than the length, then add a comma and then end.

Hope this helps anyone that may need something like this :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Special case treatment for the last element of a range in Google Go's text templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747054/special-case-treatment-for-the-last-element-of-a-range-in-google-gos-text-templ)

Comment: Hi, as helm uses go template, the question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747054/special-case-treatment-for-the-last-element-of-a-range-in-google-gos-text-templ 

You just need to add an extra `if` statement as mentioned in the answer